# Compare user input string to text file python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file filled with sample usernames and I would like to compare it to a user input to see if there is a match. If content matches it will return "This is a match" and if not it will return "That is not a match."

```
filename = 'UserNames.txt'

with open(filename) as f_obj:
    nameLists = f_obj.read()

name = input("Enter a username: ")

if name in nameLists:
    print(name + " is a match" )
else:
    print( name + "is not a match")
```

This worked to a degree but will return is a match if the user entered something similar. Ex: text file has blizz1730, user enters blizz. It comes out as a match

Comment: show us, what have you attempted!

Comment: I have updated with the code I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the words with spaces and compared with each word to find the match.

```
name = 'blizz'
nameLists='wla asdnfas blizz1730'
if name in nameLists.split():
    print(name + " is a match" )
else:
    print( name + " is not a match")
```

output:

```
blizz is not a match
```

Comment: If by accept, you mean upvote, then I have but since I do not have enough reputation, it will not reflect publicly.